# Migrating Active Directory accounts from one Mac to another using Migration Assistant

Tags: migration, active-directory, migration-assistant, network-user

Is it possible to migrate Active Directory network accounts from one Mac to another with Migration assistant? They don't show up in Migration Assistant; only the local accounts do.

Comment: Are your network accounts locally stored, using the [mobile account](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18885) option?

Answer (score 1):

If you add mobile capability they show up.  But so far from what I've seen the account migrates over but not all of the files. The home directory is empty on the target Mac.